# How can I give shadow effect to the form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing code in vb.net.I have a form and i need to give shadow to the form. I have searched but cannot get the correct answer. please assist me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your form:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ClassStyle |= 0x00020000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

**Source**: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19277/Let-Your-Form-Drop-a-Shadow

Comment: No sorry, I don't think you can. This is very limited. If you want to accomplish more with your forms, you should probably try and create your project with WPF. It is much more flexible for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Using GDI you can do it..

Follow this **[Drop Shadow on your Form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19258/Transparent-drop-shadow-in-C-GDI)**

and try this **[Form with shadow](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=71862&lngWId=1)**